# PyCharm: Timeout waiting for response on 113 after pandas dataframe pop

Tags: pandas, debugging, timeout, pycharm

The debugger is usually working just fine, but for some reason, the pop function gets it stuck.

If I put a breakpoint before this line, I can step over line-by-line as usual, but when it gets to this line it gets stuck in the same way; And when I step over again after executing this line, the whole program gets stuck as if I just stepped over a function that contains an infinite loop.

If I put a breakpoint after this line, the variables and watches windows say "collecting data..." for a long time, until it turns into "Timeout waiting for response on 113".

Also, if I simply run without debugging, everything works fine (well, everything but the errors I need the debugger for...)

These are the main lines, after them I get these timeouts:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "Table.csv"), header=0, index_col=0)
y = df.pop(column)
```

Why does it happen? Is there any way I can fix it?

**EDIT:** It has nothing to do with the pop function! I tried the following line:

```
y = df[column]
print y
```

And the same happens. Though it prints just fine...

**EDIT 2:** I didn't address this question because I solved my problem without debugging; But now the debugger works with no problems. I don't know whether it is because I am using another computer or because I just updated to 2017.2...
So in short, the problem was solved for me, but I am not sure it was solved for everyone...

Comment: What's the pycharm version you are using?

Comment: I am having a similar issue debugging `pandas` on `pycharm`. I tried updating my 'pycharm' but it did not work my `pycharm` version is  2017.1.5 and my 'pandas' version is 0.19.2

Comment: @bloop i noticed that if i use the option `view as DataFrame` the debugging works fine

Comment: @eliavs 'view as DataFrame' doesn't even appear.
I am using the the latest version, 2017 (Premium)

Comment: @bloop where are you looking? look at this example (bottom right) https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/pycharm/files/2017/02/data_view.png